# Is there any way I can install Ubuntu on my mediatek(arm64)

Tags: lenovo, chromebook, arm64, crouton, mediatek

I have a Lenovo 100e 2nd Generation Chromebook with a MediaTek CPU. (arm64). I originally wanted Windows 10 but that isn't possible. so I'm now leaning towards Ubuntu. I have tried this command line (In Crosh and VT-2) `**sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t unity**` But I ended up getting this error `**sudo: The "no new privileges" flag is set, which prevents sudo from running as root. sudo: If sudo is running in a container, you may need to adjust the container configuration to disable the flag. chronos@sycamore-rev5 / $ **`

I'm at a loss atm. And would like to proceed with Ubuntu on my Lenovo.
If anyone has any insight please let me know.

Please note:
Write Protection is off. And I am in Developers mode on chromeOS: V123 (Dev Channel.)

Comment: Installing ubuntu on arm laptops is usually not easy. Try this instead https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en

Comment: Is this your Lenovo Chromebook board name? Lenovo 100e Chromebook Gen 2 PHASER [Wiki mrchromebox Tech Supported Devices](https://wiki.mrchromebox.tech/Supported_Devices)
[Chrultrabook supported devices](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udREts28cIrCL5tnPj3WpnOPOhWk76g3--tfWbtxi6Q/edit?pli=1#gid=0)
[MrChromebox Tech FAQ](https://mrchromebox.tech/#faq)
[HexDump0815 Notes and Ideas supporting MediaTek Chromebooks](https://github.com/hexdump0815/linux-mainline-on-arm-chromebooks)

Comment: This Chromebook has variants with ARM, Intel, and AMD processors https://www.rtings.com/laptop/reviews/lenovo/100e-chromebook-2nd-gen-2019 OP has the ARM processor variant, which mrchromebox does not support

Comment: What is the Chromebook board name? https://www.aboutchromebooks.com/news/3-simple-ways-to-find-your-chromebook-board-and-brand-name/